# Kustomize/Kubernetes - Nested envFrom injection

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I'm trying to add envs injection based on `envFrom`

A simplified structure looks something like that:

```
├── base
│   ├   ─ backend
    │   ├── backend.properties
    │   ├── app1
    │   │   ├── app1_backend.properties
        ├   ── deployment.yaml
    │   │   ├── ingress.yaml
    │   │   ├── kustomization.yaml
    ├── common.properties
    ├── frontend
    │   ├── app1
        │   ├── app1_frontend.properties
    │   │   ├── deployment.yaml
    │   │   ├── ingress.yaml
    │   │   ├── kustomization.yaml
    │   │   └── service.yaml
    │   ├── frontend.properties
    │   └── kustomization.yaml
    └── kustomization.yaml
```

I would like to generate properties on the main level(common), backend/frontend level, and particular app level.
So I was trying to add the following patch on main level and it works:

```
  - op: add
    path: /spec/template/spec/containers/0/envFrom
    value:
    - configMapRef:
        name: common-properties
```

and following code to nested directories(backend/frontend/particular app)

```
- op: add
  path: "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/envFrom/-"
  value:
    configMapRef:
      name: backend-properties
```

But it doesn't work with the following error:

```
add operation does not apply: doc is missing path: "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/envFrom/-": missing value
```

I have seen some examples on GitHub where that syntax was used: https://github.com/search?l=YAML&p=1&q=%2Fspec%2Ftemplate%2Fspec%2Fcontainers%2F0%2FenvFrom%2F-&type=Code (you have to be logged in to see results) And I'm not sure this stopped work on specific Kustomize version(I'm using the newest version - 4.5.3) or it never worked

I have already written some Kustomize patches and syntax with `/-` to resources usually worked fine to resources that already exist on the manifest.
It's possible to inject that `envFrom` on different levels?

Comment: It would help if you included in your question the original manifest you're trying to patch and a `kustomization.yaml` and patch that reproduce the problem you're asking about.

Comment: I don't understand the question, exactly. Please clarify, and add a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks guys for suggestions, please check my newest comment in thread.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to diagnose your problem without a reproducible example, but if I start with this `Deployment`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: example
          image: docker.io/alpine:latest
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: example-config
```

And use this `kustomization.yaml`, which includes your patch without
changes:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- deployment.yaml

patches:
  - target:
      kind: Deployment
      name: example
    patch: |-
      - op: add
        path: "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/envFrom/-"
        value:
          configMapRef:
            name: backend-properties
```

Then everything seems to work and I get the resulting output from
`kustomize build`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: example-config
        - configMapRef:
            name: backend-properties
        image: docker.io/alpine:latest
        name: example
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @larsks. You are right this piece of code is working but I was trying to do it in a little different way. Please check my newest comment in the thread.